# Spinner like functionality in Bash when using an autocomplete script that takes a few seconds to complete

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, autocomplete, oclif

I have a CLI application that uses Oclif and NodeJS. I have an autocomplete script that looks like this:

```
# func gets called for the exec binart when Tab is pressed
# eg exec [Tab] [Tab] calls __func()

__func()
{
    Perform an http request that takes 2-3 seconds
    Populate COMPREPLY with autocomplete values
}

complete -o nospace -F __func exec
```

Since pressing Tab takes a few seconds, it would be nice to have a spinner like functionality in the shell, so that the user can see that the autocomplete is running.

How can I achieve this? Instead of a spinner a progress bar would be nice, or some dots that would indicate loading (...).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to call a spinner before and after your command?

Example spinner:

- [oclif spinner](https://oclif.io/docs/spinner)
- [node-spinner](https://github.com/helloIAmPau/node-spinner) (has more visual options)

Example with your code:

```
    __func()
    {
        spinner.start()
        Perform an http request that takes 2-3 seconds
        Populate COMPREPLY with autocomplete values
        spinner.end()
    }

    complete -o nospace -F __func exec
```

Comment: __func is written in bash, while spinner.start() / end() are only available in nodejs.